# polymer hero transition in shadow dom

Tags: transition, polymer, web-component

I have a hero transition sitting within a polymer element. The documentation states that the transition will work for up to 1 level of shadow root. (https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-animated-pages). However, it doesn't work.

If I move the element outside of the shadow dom, it works as expected.

```
<polymer-element name="x-el" noscript>
  <template>
    <div hero-id="hero-test" hero> GO HERO </div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<core-animated-pages transitions="hero-transition cross-fade">
        <section>
            // works
            <div hero-id="hero-test" hero> GO HERO </div>

            // doesn't work
            <x-el></x-el>
        </section>

        <section>
            <div hero-id="hero-test" hero> YAY </div>
        </section>
</core-animated-pages>
```

Live demo: http://codepen.io/nicolasrannou/pen/zxNYMw

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: To be more clear, the transition only works in one direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove "section" outside your custom element then it's gonna work!

```
    <!--<section>-->
        <x-el onclick="stuff(1);"></x-el>
    <!--</section>-->
```

Check this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yygydK

Goodluck

Comment: Took me a while to figure this out, basically you don't wrap an element with another `session` or `div` when it's used for `hero-transitions`.